# Why EF code is not selecting a single column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have used this to pick just a single column from the collection but it doesn't and throws casting error.

```
ClientsDAL ClientsDAL = new DAL.ClientsDAL();
var clientsCollection= ClientsDAL.GetClientsCollection();
var projectNum = clientsCollection.Where(p => p.ID == edit.Clients_ID).Select(p => p.ProjectNo).ToString();
```

Method:

```
public IEnumerable<Clients> GetClientsCollection(string name = "")
{
    IEnumerable<Clients> ClientsCollection;
    var query = uow.ClientsRepository.GetQueryable().AsQueryable();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name));
    }

    ClientsCollection = (IEnumerable<Clients>)query;
    return ClientsCollection;
}
```

Comment: First of all, the cast of IQueryable<T> to IEnumerable<T> will fail. Use .AsEnumerable instead. Secondly, your selected property clientsCollection.Where(p => p.ID == edit.Clients_ID).Select(p => p.ProjectNo) is of type IQueryable<T> (where T is the type of ProjectNo), so .ToString() on this property will always return just the type (unless you've created an extension method for that)

Comment: I think you need `First` or `FirstOrDefault` instead `Select(..).ToString()`

Comment: Also, note that by casting an IQueryable to an IEnumerable of that type, you are implicitly enumerating the query and therefore materializing the results.

Comment: @AleksAndreev put that in answer box and i will mark it. done
thanks to the others too

Comment: @JohnnyShallow done. Please note that I've not tested it (as I usually do), but I hope that idea is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DevilSuichiro said in comments you should not cast to `IEnumerable<T>` just call `.AsEnumerable()` it will keep laziness.

But in your case it looks like you do not need that at all because `First` or `FirstOrDefault` work with `IQueryable` too.

To get a single field use this code

```
clientsCollection
  .Where(p => p.ID == edit.Clients_ID)
  .Select(p => p.ProjectNo)
  .First() // if you sure that at least one item exists
```

Or (more safe)

```
var projectNum = clientsCollection
  .Where(p => p.ID == edit.Clients_ID)
  .Select(p => (int?)p.ProjectNo)
  .FirstOrDefault();

if (projectNum != null)
{
    // you find that number
}
else
{
    // there is no item with such edit.Clients_ID
}
```

Or even simpler with null propagation

```
var projectNum = clientsCollection
  .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == edit.Clients_ID)?.ProjectNo;
```